# How to use PubSubHubbub to get video comments notifications on YouTube using YouTube API v3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, websub

How to use PubSubHubbub to receive notification when a user comments on a YouTube video

Also, What is the topic url? For example for videos it is https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=CHANNEL_ID.

Comment: Could this possible be a solution to subscribe to comments or better to replies, where one has not posted anything / or not been mentioned?